# Why Doesn't Python Reapply Formula In This While Loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, variables, while-loop

The below code goes into an infinite loop, but I'm trying to understand why Python doesn't update the value of prob each time through the loop and instead binds prob to 0. Each time Python evaluates whether prob < .99, why doesn't it update the value of prob too? PLEASE DO NOT tell me to place prob in the while loop. I'm trying to understand why Pyhton behaves the way it does. Can someone explain to me why prob is no longer bound to x after entering the while loop?

```
days = 365 
i = 0 
x = 1
prob = 1 - x 

while prob < .99: 
    i += 1 
    x = x * ((days - i)/float(days))

print i
```

Comment: Why would the value of `prob` ever change? It is set initially to `0`, then never changed in the loop. Why would you ever expect the value to change? If you want that behavior, add the line `prob = 1 - x` as the last line of the loop (or whatever you want it to do).

Comment: why doesn't re-evaluate prob each time it checks the condition prob < .99? why does it just bind it to 0 whereas if it were placed in the loop, it would re-valuate it each time? why is prob no longer bound to x? as i said in the prompt, i know how to make this code work, so i'm not looking for answers that tell me to place prob in the while loop. i'm just trying to understand python's behavior in this case and why it behaves the way it does.

Comment: *"why is prob no longer bound to x?"* That is your misconception. `x` is not "bound" to `prob`. The statement `prob = 1 - x` says "set the variable `prob` to be `1` minus whatever the value of `x` is". It does not care what happens to `x` after that, it just read the value of `x`.

Comment: gotcha..it just seems like it would be more efficient/logical if python re-evaluated the value of x when invoking prob rather than setting it equal to 0 and moving on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

prob is not updated. The expression 1 - x is replaced immediately by the 1-1=0 and prob won't be linked to x anymore.
The - operator creates a new object(!) that has nothing to do with x and binds this new object to prob.

Answer (score 3):

Nowhere in the loop do you update the value of prob.

Are you looking for something like this?

```
days = 365 
i = 0 
x = 1
prob = 0 # Prob initialised once to a value

while prob < .99: 
    i += 1 
    x = x * ((days - i)/float(days))
    prob = 1 - x # Value of prob is updated each time the loop is executed

print i
```

The way you currently have it, prob is set before the loop, then the loop continually checks against the same value of prob and so never exits.

Answer (score 2):

Python statements are not rules (which are reapplied at every step). They are one-time commands which cause Python to do something. So

```
prob = 1 - x
```

binds the current value of the `1 - x` to the variable `prob`.
If you want that to happen again, you have to place that statement inside the `while-loop`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the code:

```
prob = 1 -x
```

inside the loop. That way it gets executed each time the loop loops.

```
days = 365 
i = 0 
x = 1
prob = 1 - x 

while prob < .99: 
    i += 1 
    x = x * ((days - i)/float(days))
    prob = 1 - x  # Here, you see?

print i
```